# Unexpected token when refreshing page using Html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I'm using `Html5Mode(true)` in my AngularJS app. This works fine when I browse to my website like this:

```
http://www.example.com
```

This then gets transformed to:

```
http://www.example.com/home/index
```

And my page is rendered fine.

But, when I press F5 then I get a lot of errors in my console window:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.example.com/home/js/jquery/jquery.min.js". index:22
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.example.com/home/js/slider/angular.rangeSlider.css". index:16
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.min.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.example.com/home/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js". index:25
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.example.com/home/js/angular/angular.min.js". index:24
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular-resource.min.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.example.com/home/js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js". index:26
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I've already configured my `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [L]
```

But this doesn't work when I refresh the page. Then I get errors. Is there something I'm missing?

---

I am using `ui-router`. Not sure if that makes any difference. My route simply looks like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/index');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/tpl/home.html'
    })
    .state('home.index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: '/tpl/home_index.html'
    })
```

Anyone any idea why refreshing the page results in the errors I posted above?

Comment: I have just found the solution. The problem is that you are rewriting all paths to server. You need to create rule to exclude folders Content and Scripts

Answer (score 0):

You should only rewrite the router urls that needed,for example:

/home - index.html

/product/1234 - index.html

Don't rewrite all requests to index.html. because most of urls should not be rewrited.